# Working with CGS units when calculating magnetic moment

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, units

I am attempting to calculate the total magnetic moment of a spherical object with known volume magnetic susceptibility $\chi$ in an $\mathbf{H}$ field of 1000 Oe. I need to do this in CGS units.

1. Let's say that the volume susceptibility is 10 in SI units (i.e. unitless). I know I can convert this into CGS units using the conversion $1/4\pi$ Thus we have $\chi = 10/(4\pi) = 0.8$. **My first question is, how do I specify the units of this quantity (in CGS)? Is the susceptibility still effectively unitless, or does dividing by $4 \pi$ do something weird?**
2. Assuming we're in the linear regime, I then multiply my susceptibility by $\mathbf{H}$ to get magnetization (dipole moment per unit volume), and finally multiply the volume $V$ of the spherical object to get total dipole moment
   $$ \mathbf{m} = \chi \mathbf{H} V.$$ **Are the units now  Oe $\mathrm{cm^3}$? If so, how do I convert these to emu?**

Comment: Re 1, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility#In_CGS_units

Comment: Re 2, if you are working in CGS why are you using the meter as the unit of length?